# How can I use jquery to make a get request on a url that will return xml?

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

I am trying to access a store's api and get back an xml response, currently I am using a xmlhttprequest

```
function GetInfo()
{
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://partner.tcgplayer.com/x2/phl.asmx/p?pk=TCGTEST&s=New Phyrexia&p=Flameborn Viron", false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    alert(xmlHttp.responseText);


}
```

(jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YXRdu/)

but I am not having any success. I feel like it is probably due to the same origin access policy but I am really unsure how to work around it. I have google the problem but I am not sure how I can implement cors on a remote server that I don't have access to. I know the url is valid, when I enter it in my browser I get a xml data back.

I am really unsure what I am doing wrong, any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the server allows JSONP, which works cross-domain. If not, you'll have to get the XML on the server-side (of your own server) and then you can send it to Javascript via AJAX.

Comment: I've tried using ajax....fails for the same reasons as xml request...same origin policy error

Comment: You said the remote server gave an XML response, so `$.getJSON` isn't going to help you in any case. *If* the server supported it, you'd use `$.get()` with `dataType:'jsonp'`. But chances are it doesn't...check the documentation for your web service to see what it says.

Comment: Actually my previous comment wasn't quite right...you CAN do JSONP with `$.getJSON` by adding a `?callback=?` ("or similar, as defined by the server-side API") to the end of the URL, and the fact that it's XML isn't really the issue...although JSONP only returns JSON data so if it actually works then it probably means the server supports both XML and JSON. (There's also the possibility of sending XML as part of a JSON response but that's highly unlikely.)

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetInfo()
{
    var test = $('#cardname').val();

   var jqxhr = $.get('http://partner.tcgplayer.com/x2/phl.asmx/p?pk=TCGTEST&s=New%20Phyrexia&p=Flameborn%20Viron', function(data) {
alert(data);

}).done(function() { alert("second success"); })
.fail(function() { alert("error"); })
.always(function() { alert("finished"); });
}




GetInfo();
```

There is a cross domain issue :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://partner.tcgplayer.com/x2/phl.asmx/p?pk=TCGTEST&s=New%20Phyrexia&p=Flameborn%20Viron.
>   Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

You should try the server side method.

Comment: yeah will probably have too that